# How to use styled components in React in order to get keyframe animations

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components, keyframe

I am new to React and specifically trying to use styled components and keyframes.

I am trying to get the homepage header h1 to slide in.

I followed some documentation but I feel there is something missing or that I have it out of order.

Here is the code:

//Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';


const Heading = keyframes`
  0% { top: -3.125em; }
  100% { top: 3em;
`;

const home = styled.div`
    min-height: 95vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
`;

const homeHeader = styled.div`
  h1 {
    font-weight: lighter;
    animation: Heading;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  // Animation
  animation: ${Heading}
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;

export const Home = () => (
    <div className="home">
      <header className="homeHeader">
        <h1>Welcome to Freight Mule</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
);

export default Home;
```

Any help here in understanding how to get the keyframe and animation to work would be super helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Several things are wrong :

1. You don't actually use the component created by `styled-component`. When you do

```
const Div = styled.div`
  background-color: blue;
`
```

you've just created a new React component that you can use in any render method. So your `Home` component becomes that I upppercased (react expects custom components to be uppercased) and renamed a bit the components to avoid duplicate variables):

```
const Home = () => (
  <HomeDiv>
    <HomeHeader>
      <h1>Welcome to Freight Mule</h1>
    </HomeHeader>
  </HomeDiv>
);
```

2. To animate the `top` property, you need to add initial `top` information to the Header. Besides, I think you didn't want to apply the animation on the `h1` so I removed it

```
const HomeHeader = styled.div`
  h1 {
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  animation: ${Heading};
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;
```

3. Optionnal: To actually see the animation going from -3.125em to 3em, you need to remove the `justify-content:center;` from the `HomeDiv` css declaration. Otherwise, you'll see an animation going from the center of the div to 3em.

Here the full code:

```
const Heading = keyframes`
  0% { top: -3.125em; }
  100% { top: 3em;}
`;

const HomeDiv = styled.div`
  min-height: 95vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
`;

const HomeHeader = styled.div`
  h1 {
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  animation: ${Heading};
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;

const Home = () => (
  <HomeDiv>
    <HomeHeader>
      <h1>Welcome to Freight Mule</h1>
    </HomeHeader>
  </HomeDiv>
);
```

And here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-cherry-er3mn)

Comment: where did you import the keyframes variable from?----

const Heading = keyframes`
  0% { top: -3.125em; }
  100% { top: 3em;}
`;

Comment: https://styled-components.com/docs/api?#keyframes

Comment: i realize it was part of the package like 30 second after I asked. I worked great thanks